# How to use a custom "__RequestVerificationToken"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've made a partial view like this (location: `MyController/_Form.cshtml`):

```
<form asp-antiforgery="true">
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Some actions in Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok(new { succeeded = true });
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetTemplate()
{
    string template = _viewRender<string>("MyController/_Form", null);
    return Ok({ template = template });
}
```

The [_viewRender](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/master/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs) is a service to convert from partial view to a string.

I've tested with these steps:

Using jquery to make a request from client to server to get the template and append to some div.

```
let onSuccess = function (data) {
    $(data.template).appendTo('.myDiv');
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/GetTemplate',
    method: 'POST'
}).done(onSuccess).fail(onError);
```

And the event to detect submiting form looks like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=text]', function () {
    let _this = $(this);

    let token = _this.parent().find('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    let onSuccess = function (data) {
        console.log(data); // should be: Object:{succeeded:true}
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/MyController/Test',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(onSuccess).fail(onError);
});
```

When I made the request, I always got error code `404 - not found` on `Console` tab.

I'm sure the path is correct. So, I've tried to remove `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute from `Test` action and tried again. It's working fine (request status code `200`).

So, I guess the problem (which gave 404 error) came from the token. I've used developer tool to check again and I'm sure that I have a token. But I don't know how to check the token is valid or not.

The token was generated from server. I just made a request to get it and appended to body. Then, re-sent it to server. But server didn't accept it.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

This is how it's done in ASP.NET Core...

In `Startup.cs` you'll need to setup the anti-forgery header name.

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

You need to do this because by default anti-forgery will only consider form data and we want it to work with ajax too.

In your `.cshtml` file you'll need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` which will render a hidden input with the validation token.

Finally in your ajax code you need to setup the request header before sending.

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
}
```

So in your case the ajax code will look like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/Test',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(onSuccess).fail(onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, I use a custom filter instead of ValidateAntiForgeryToken.  I don't remember why.  Probably ValidateAntiForgeryToken doesn't work with AJAX requests.

Here's the code for the custom filter I use.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPostsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
        }
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //  Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            //  Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes
            //  to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie?.Value;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, the token goes in the request header not the data part.  I add it to the header using ajaxSetup in the layout file.  That way I don't have to worry about remembering to add it to every AJAX request.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried with your advice multiple times but not successful. Sorry, I forgot tag `asp.net-core` on my question. Your attribute requires namespace `System.Web.Mvc` which isn't supported in asp.net core. Thanks, I think it should work if I can translate it to the version which works on asp.net core.